# jquery clearing $.post data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a multi-part form. Each part executes a new script. When each script is executed it will check for required data. If said data is missing it will return a string "false"

part 1 fails correctly (calls `highlight()`) but part 2 just spits out "false" bypassing the `highlight` function as if `data !== false`. I've tried clearing data but this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
    $('.submit').live('click', function(){
    var bclick = $(this);   
    var frm = "../../scripts/retain-" + $(this).attr('rel') + ".php";
    var fields = $('#retain-form').serialize();

    $.post(frm, fields, function(data){
        if(data == 'false'){
            highlight();
            data = '';
        }else{
            var nForm = $(bclick).attr('rel');
            nForm = parseInt(nForm[4]) + 1;
            $(bclick).attr('rel', "form" + nForm);
            $('#retain-steps').html(data);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `highlight` function should receive a `bclick` param

```
function highlight(bclick){
 ...
}
```

and be called like this:

```
highlight(bclick);
```

You should pass the `bclick` param to your `highlight` function, so it can know which part to highlight.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the reply. not the solution though. whats happening is the initial click calls "script1.php" which will reply with a new form (form2) if all the required data was passed. when form2 data is passed to script2, if the required data is not there it should spit back "false". $.post data is not catching "false" the second time it just acts as if the valid data was received.

Comment: Programmer error. some how i was returning " false" instead of "false"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do and what's going wrong here, but one thing to be careful with is using the type coercing `==` comparison around [JavaScript's "falsy" values](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).  Since `"" == false`, you run into some unintuitive bugs around that.  Try using the strict `===` comparison in your conditionals instead.

Comment: thanks for the post. since im unaware of a way to return a boolean false to jquery i just went with a string "false". I did end up figuring it out. thanks!